Making mysql write more to ram and less to SSD
What are some tunning options that could make MySQL (8.0.36) write more to ram memory and less to SSD ? To have less SSD wear not to optimize performance.
Do these two affect amount of bytes written to disk at all ? The way I know it, SSDs need to rearange data and constantly move it around when writing new data, so I am thinking if these options delays writes to SSD, then it might write less data ? Since it might already be optimally arranged while in Ram ?
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout = 3

I also have innodb_buffer_pool_size = 90G
What are some [other] variables that I can tune so that it writes less to SSD and more to ram ?
Having tables fully stored in memory would be nice, but I think they are too big for that to work properly.
The server has 128 GB ram, largest database is around 100-150 GB.
Would other variables help ? e.g innodb_log_buffer_size, innodb_redo_log_capacity ?

You can mount a database containing filesystem with -noatime option. That will disable updating of atime on each write to the database.

"To have less SSD wear"...to be honest, with the small database you have, your SSD is far more likely to die of old age first. Sounds like you're trying to solve a problem you won't have.

The size of the database does not wear the SSD, the amount of write / updates does. I use these in search engine crawlers that crawls around 70 million domains and updates many records (last crawl date, domain title, keywords, links, etc). The Percentage Used: in smartctl reaches 100% in 6-10 months and at around 200% you have good chances for SSD to fail.

And given the high[er] NVME write speed, you have good chances to reach the wear limits very fast.

You could totally eliminate writes if you set read_only=ON and innodb_read_only=ON. You could even operate the MySQL instance on non-writable media, like a CDROM disk. But I assume you want to allow database writes, but minimize the write I/O.
You could also stop using InnoDB as the storage engine. You could use MyISAM or even MEMORY.
Here are some other options to reduce write I/O without completely blocking writes.

disable_log_bin - do not write binary logs.
general_log=OFF - do not write to the general query log.
slow_query_log=OFF - do not write to the slow query log.
sort_buffer_size=N - use more memory for sorting a batch of rows; if a result set can be sorted in a single batch, it doesn't need to use disk I/O.
innodb_doublewrite=OFF - skip writes to the InnoDB doublewrite buffer, which occur by default on page flushes.
innodb_flush_method - read manual for details; the best setting depends on your server and OS.
innodb_flush_neighbors=0 - should already be 0 by default, but double-check it.
innodb_checksum_algorithm=none - small benefit, but possibly reduces SSD write wear.

Here are a couple of other options which are available if you still use MySQL 5.x, but not if you use MySQL 8.0+.

innodb_support_xa=OFF - removed in MySQL 8.0 (it is always enabled if the binary log is enabled).
sync_frm=0 -
removed in MySQL 8.0.


Thank you Bill, can you tell me why you also mentioned MyISAM next to MEMORY as alternative storage engine ? Would MyISAM have advantages over InnoDB in this case ?

MyISAM uses buffered I/O; the filesystem cache will help to reduce excessive writes.

Given that the data is bigger than ram...

Worry about "locality if reference"
Shrink datatypes (to make tables smaller, hence write sizes)
Improve indexes (to decrease disk reads and writes)
Minimize disk reads (to improve buffer_pool caching and efficiency of writes, especially index updates)
Use the SlowLog to find the naughtiest queries -- they are likely to be the ones that are causing the most trouble above.

